# How do I make an AnnotationProcessor test *subtypes* of the annotated type?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I wish to create an annotation which will test the annotated type (which may be an interface) and all its subtypes, and throw a compile error if any tested type is a concrete class without a no-arg constructor. I'm able to test the type that actually bears the annotation, no problem. Testing the subtypes is where I'm lost. How can I accomplish this? Source code below:

### NoArgConstructorRequired.java

```
package mshare.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface NoArgConstructorRequired {
}
```

### NoArgConststructorRequiredProcessor.java

```
package mshare.annotation;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.Messager;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind;
import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.type.ExecutableType;
import javax.lang.model.type.TypeVisitor;
import javax.lang.model.util.SimpleTypeVisitor7;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("mshare.annotation.NoArgConstructorRequired")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
public class NoArgConstructorRequiredProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    // Tests if the visited type has no args
    private static final TypeVisitor<Boolean, Void> NO_ARGS_VISITOR = new SimpleTypeVisitor7<Boolean, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean visitExecutable(ExecutableType t, Void v) {
            return Boolean.valueOf(t.getParameterTypes().isEmpty());
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        Messager messager = processingEnv.getMessager();

        for (TypeElement typeElement : annotations) {
            for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(typeElement)) {
                if (!isOkay(element)) {
                    messager.printMessage(
                            Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                            element.getSimpleName() + " lacks a no-arg constructor",
                            element
                            );
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isOkay(Element element) {
        if (element.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.ABSTRACT)) {
            // class is not concrete
            return true;
        }

        for (Element subElement : element.getEnclosedElements()) {
            if (subElement.getKind() == ElementKind.CONSTRUCTOR) {
                if (subElement.asType().accept(NO_ARGS_VISITOR, null).booleanValue()) {
                    // has a no-arg constructor
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As Louis Wasserman's answer seems to be the best that can be done for now, I've accepted it. I'll accept someone else's answer if someone comes up with a non-evil way to make it work for interfaces, too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps the annotation should be marked [`@Inherited`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html), which marks annotations as "descending through subclasses."

Comment: Unfortunately, using @Inherited only allows the annotation to be inherited from superclasses, not interfaces.

Comment: Ah.  That qualification was not clear.  I don't believe there's any good alternative, in that case, except to have your annotation processor manually walk up the supertype tree.

Comment: Walking *up* the tree wouldn't be a problem. It's walking *down* the tree that's an issue. Modifying the original entry to make clear that the annotated type might be an interface.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't walk up the tree instead of down.  From what it looks like, your objective is to check, for each class, whether or not any superclass or superinterface has a @NoArgConstructorRequired annotation, no?  Is this not a thing you can do with annotation processors?

Comment: I see it.  Ugh.  You can't use an annotation processor on unannotated classes.

Comment: ...I've got no ideas left.  I'm not sure what you're suggesting is doable at all.